# Why is PowerShell "not recognized" when installing Chocolatey?

Tags: windows, powershell, chocolatey

I went to the [Chocolatey website](https://chocolatey.org/) and copied the text for installing it and pasted into the administrator `cmd.exe` (using Windows 7). When I run the command I get:

> 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This [GitHub article](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Installation) with Chocolatey installation instructions says:

> This really is the easiest method because it requires no configuration of PowerShell prior to executing it.

Comment: you have some faulty powershell installation, or it is missing from the Windows PATH variable. Run in an admin cmd: set PATH=%PATH%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that **@balint** was right about the path being incorrect. The path variable at some point had gotten replaced instead of appended to. I was able to install Chocolatey successfully after appending all the paths that had been erased previously!

> you have some faulty PowerShell installation, or it is missing from the Windows PATH variable. Run in an administrator cmd:
>
> ```
> cmd> set PATH=%PATH%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
> ```

Comment: This added PowerShell to my PATH in Windows 8.1 Professional. Thanks :)